# How to get a column total using SUMX and table expression in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table expression inside the `SUMX()` function.
How can I get a total of column "Open" in my scenario?

```
TestMeasure =
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE (
                FILTER (
                    SumByClaim,
                    SumByClaim[TransactionDate] >= FIRSTDATE ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
                        && SumByClaim[TransactionDate] <= LASTDATE ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
                ),
                SumByClaim[ClaimNumber],
                SumByClaim[ClaimantID],
                SumByClaim[ClaimStatus],
                "MaxTransDate", MAX ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
            ),
            "Open", IF (
                SumByClaim[ClaimStatus] = "Open"
                    && [MaxTransDate] = MAX ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] ),
                1,
                0
            )
        ),
        [Open]
    )
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Thanks @CR7SMS.

But now it looks a little high:

I tried:

```
TestMeasure3 =
    SUMX(SumByClaim,
        SUMX (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    FILTER (
                        SumByClaim,
                        SumByClaim[TransactionDate] >= FIRSTDATE ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
                            && SumByClaim[TransactionDate] <= LASTDATE ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
                    ),
                    SumByClaim[ClaimNumber],
                    SumByClaim[ClaimantID],
                    SumByClaim[ClaimStatus],
                    "MaxTransDate", MAX ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
                ),
                "Open", IF (
                    SumByClaim[ClaimStatus] = "Open"
                        && [MaxTransDate] = MAX ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] ),
                    1,
                    0
                )
            ),
            [Open]
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: What does the grand total show currently?

Comment: Total should be 335. But on a picture its 12

Answer (score 0):

I added SUMX over the calculation and it is giving me a higher total. I am not sure if the results are what you are looking for but you can give it a try:

```
TestMeasure = 
SUMX(SumByClaim,SUMX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER (
                SumByClaim,
                SumByClaim[TransactionDate] >= FIRSTDATE ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
                    && SumByClaim[TransactionDate] <= LASTDATE ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
            ),
            SumByClaim[ClaimNumber],
            SumByClaim[ClaimantID],
            SumByClaim[ClaimStatus],
            "MaxTransDate", MAX ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] )
        ),
        "Open", IF (
            SumByClaim[ClaimStatus] = "Open"
                && [MaxTransDate] = MAX ( SumByClaim[TransactionDate] ),
            1,
            0
        )
    ),
    [Open]
))
```